# Python PyQt5 Progress Bar

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, progress-bar

I need to make a Progress Bar that has "multiple stops". We are currently working on a project to design a train controller. In one window we select the cities where we want to stop and if one city is arrived the Progress Bar should go up (for example if we have 10 stops total after the first stop the Progress Bar should go to 10%).
Any ideas on how to realize it?

Comment: Isn't [QProgressBar](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprogressbar.html) enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that [QProgressBar](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprogressbar.html) operates on `int`s and is exactly what you want:

```py
myProgess = QProgressBar()
myProgress.setMaximum(totalNumberOfStations)

for i in range(1, totalNumberOfStations + 1):
    myProgress.setValue(i)
```